# Trouble Decoding Encoded game cheat file

Tags: security, encryption, decode, malware

So i noticed someone was cheating in i game i play and i wanted the file to analyse how the cheats were written and how they work, i do not intend to use them!
I downloaded the zipped file in windows sandbox (as i want to be safe) and extracted it then opened it in vs code.
I got this message first
[image: vs code message before viewing the code]

then when i continue the code looks like this
[image: the code in some sort of encryption]

i am not very experienced so any help in how i can decode this or any errors i made would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Since you're not very experienced, you're not going to get very far.  You have to open the file in a [hex viewer](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/file-dump) and painstakingly figure out what each numeric value represents.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc okay I am not completely inexperienced as I'm studying a cyber security and forensic computing course and I self learn at home but of course I have so much to learn! is it not possible to convert hex to a numeric value using a premade decoder or to perhaps write a code myself to do it for me?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc what is it we can see in my screen shot? as its not encoded just a mess of symbols?

Comment: Okay, the first two characters on your screenshot are "MZ".  What does that mean?  What game is this file from?  Again, you need a hex viewer to pick out what the next dozen or so symbols represent.  You can convert hex to decimal with an online calculator.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zbikowski

Comment: This is a reverse engineering question and there is a [site](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) for those questions. But the quick answer is to disassemble/decompile it with ghidra and/or IDA-Pro and then begin the painstaking process of trying to understand what the code does.